# Class template argument deduction in case of function type argument in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In the following example, template struct `A` has a constructor from a function type `T()`, and then objects of `A` are constructed: one with explicit type specification `A<int> x` and the other with template argument auto-deduction `A y`:

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    A(T f()){ f(); }
};

int foo() { return 1; }

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] A<int> x = foo; // ok everywhere
    [[maybe_unused]] A y = foo; // Clang error
}
```

This program is accepted as a whole by GCC, however Clang cannot auto-deduce the template argument:

```
error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'A'
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'A<T>' against 'int (*)()'
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'T ()' against 'int (*)()'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e9aGqoT1s

Is the program not well-formed, or Clang misses some feature required for auto-deduction?

Comment: `<functional>` has [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides) that make your code valid since c++17, seems like a clang bug?

Comment: There is a lot of type 'hidden' converting going on there - possibly it is more correct to change the constructor to `explicit A( T (*f)() ){ f(); }` and call like: `A y(foo);` (or some other more c++ scheme like std::function or template the function type)?

Comment: clang has the [same deduction issue](https://godbolt.org/z/ToK55rMnn) with `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @code_fodder, thanks, after suggested program modification the behavior is the same:  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fKTMqW43a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<functional>` has deduction guides that make your code valid since c++17, this does look like a clang bug (?) but I found no defect for this specifically.

You could however put the whole function type as a template parameter:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A{
     A(T f){ f(); }
};

int foo() { return 1; }

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] A x{ foo };
    [[maybe_unused]] A y{ foo };
    [[maybe_unused]] A z = [](){ return 1; };  // now also works with lambdas!
}
```

This compiles with clang, GCC, and MSVC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K1v7a4s7o

As an unnecessary bonus, asserting on [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<T>, "not invocable");
    A(T f){ f(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I submitted Clang bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52368

Comment: The bug migrated to GitHub and fixed: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/51710